# Xcode with Swift: How can I pass object back and forth in wizard steps?

Tags: xcode, swift, segue

I am stuck on implementing a rather simple task.
I have wizard with 3 steps in which you create an entity of course.
The wizard consists of a navigation view followed by 3 regular view.

[image]

In the contoller of the first step I create the course object and pass it to next step via the segue event:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "Step1_To_Step2") {
        let step2Controller = segue.destinationViewController as Step2Controller
        step2Controller.course = self.course
    }
}
```

What I can't figure out though is:

1. How can I pass the object when going the other way, from step 2 to step 1, for exmaple?
2. Is it good practice, memory-wise to replace the whole object each time or just specific fields within? (The object may contain an image or two)

Comment: use delegate and call delegate method from setp2 to pass data from step2 to step1. You can also use notification center to pass data.

Comment: Can you be more specific...what delegate? In which event? a code sample would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check some attached images. It may help you to understand delegate if you not already aware of it.  Attached first image is for segue and second for delegate.

**Segue**
[image]

**Result**
[image]

Comment: Ok, but I don't have a "btnPopTapped". I have the default "back button" the navigation controller provides.

Comment: If possible then Create custom UIBarButton and call delegate method from custom button method as i've done in btnPopTapped.